# onUpgrade() to perform on selective tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have three tables in my database: `authors`, `books` and `user_settings`. I'd like to occasionally add rows to the first two columns, but I don't want to overwrite any user settings.

Is it possible to call `onUpgrade()` on the first two tables, but not the third?

**EDIT**

I should clarify that I'm dealing with a preloaded database. So `authors` and `books` come with the app, but `user_settings` changes depending on user actions, and shouldn't be affected by any additions to `authors` or `books`.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. `onUpgrade()` updates database schemas, not anything per table. To add rows you wouldn't change the schema, just insert your data.

Comment: It is *your* job to implement `onUpgrade()`, so you can do (or not do) whatever you want.

Comment: @laalto I've updated my question. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I'd store user settings somewhere else if they are not related with the preloaded data. Another database, shared prefs, whatever.

Comment: But even then I don't see what onUpgrade() has to do with persisting user settings.